# Changes to vector<bitset> change values in another vector

Tags: c++, vector, bitset

Provided the following  code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> coordinate;
typedef vector<coordinate> path;

class Game {
private:
    vector<bitset<15>> board{15};
    vector<path> paths;
public:
    Game() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            string line;
            getline(cin, line);
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                if (line[j] == '.') {
                    board[i].set(j); // the problem no longer occurs after removing this line
                    if (paths.size() > 2)
                        cout << "A: " << paths[2].back().first << endl;
                    paths.emplace_back(1, make_pair(j, i));
                    if (paths.size() > 2)
                        cout << "B: " << paths[2].back().first << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Game game;
    return 0;
}
```

I run into an issue, values in my vector *paths* gets changed by the line *board[i].set(j);*. To me, it seems like these two vectors are completely unrelated.
Given the following input (this issue occurs for several inputs this is just one I tested):

```
.........xx....
..xx.....xx....
..xx...........
...............
...............
.........xx....
....xx...xx....
....xx.........
...............
...xx..xx......
...xx..xx......
...............
...............
............xx.
............xx.
```

This input yields the following output:

```
A: 2
B: 2    
A: 2
B: 2
...
A: 2
B: 2
A: 3
B: 3
A: 3
B: 3
A: 7
B: 7
A: 15
B: 15
A: 31
B: 31
A: 63
B: 63
A: 127
B: 127
A: 255
B: 255
A: 511
B: 511
A: 1023
B: 1023
A: 2047
B: 2047
A: 4095
B: 4095
A: 8191
B: 8191
A: 16383
B: 16383
A: 32767
B: 32767
...
A: 32767
B: 32767
A: 32767
B: 32767
```

One thing I have tried is changing *board[i].set(j);* to *board[i] |= 1 << j;* but this had no effect.

I cannot figure out in what way these values are changed or how to fix it, thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: "*values in my vector paths gets changed by the line board[i].set(j);*" Why do you say that exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the initialization:

```
vector<bitset<15>> board{15};
```

That's no vector with 15 elements, but a vector with one element that gets initialized with the value 15. Thus `board[i]` goes out of bounds for any i >= 1. This causes undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

If the size of the vector is fixed anyway `std::array` may be a better choice:

```
std::array<std::bitset<15>, 15> board;
```

Or initialize it in the constructor initializer list:

```
Game() : board(15) // intialize with 15 default-constructed elements
{ /* other logic */}
```

Comment: I see, I must have gotten the constructors mixed up. Using std::array works perfectly fine, thank you.